Avoiding plotting duplicate points in ggplot2
I'm looking for an easy way for ggplot() to remove duplicates before plotting points (e.g., when using geom_point) to improve plotting/render speed.
I'm working with large datasets (>100,000 rows), in which there are several columns representing different categorical descriptors of the data (location, timestep, species, etc), and a single column representing a response value of interest. Even though many of the response values are duplicated, because of those identifier columns, each row is unique, and I cannot collapse the data with unique() or dplyr::distinct(). However, I frequently need to plot the points associated with only one blocking factor (e.g., just site), at which point there are many duplicated points in the plot, and plotting can be very time consuming. I can get around this by using select to filter to specific variables used in the plot and then using distinct(), but this is clunky and slows down iteration of plotting. Are there more direct solutions?
Using data similar to my own, plotting can take quite a while (using a somewhat smaller dataset here for simplicity):
library(tidyverse)
## generate data, starting with unique combination of identifiers
data = expand_grid(site = letters[1:15], timestep = 1:100, block = 1:20)
## generate values, with most values being the same, but 2% of values being something different.
data$value = 1 + (runif(nrow(data))>0.98) * rnorm(nrow(data))

ggplot(data, aes(x = site, y = value))+
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip()

If I use select() to choose only the variables I'm plotting, I can then use distinct() to remove points that are duplicated in this plot, which dramatically speeds up plotting.
ggplot(data |> 
         select(site, value) |> 
         distinct(), 
       aes(x = site, y = value))+
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip()

However, using that approach, any changes to the plot that involve additional variables (for example, coloring points by timestep) will only work if I also update the select() call. Is there a simpler and more direct way to avoid plotting duplicate points in ggplot?

I'm wondering whether one should really hide the overall variation of values (by removing monovariate duplicates). What about binning or hexbinning or setting opacity (aes(..., alpha = ...)) or size to the count of duplicates?

Or use geom_count().

You don't need to select, you can just pass columns to distinct:
library(tidyverse)
## generate data, starting with unique combination of identifiers
data = expand_grid(site = letters[1:15], timestep = 1:100, block = 1:20)
## generate values, with most values being the same, but 2% of values being something different.
data$value = 1 + (runif(nrow(data))>0.98) * rnorm(nrow(data))

data %>% 
  distinct(site, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= site, y = value))+
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip()


You can make a function, but if you use other ggplot aesthetics you'll have to update this function to handle missing aesthetics which is a whole different question... This code uses the "embrace" (i.e. {{ <col_name }} ). If you want to understand that more checkout this guide on the dplyr website.

ggplot_distinct <- function(df, x, y){
  df %>% 
    distinct({{x}}, {{y}}) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = {{x}}, y = {{y}}))+
    geom_point()+
    coord_flip()
}

data %>% 
  ggplot_distinct(site, value)


Created on 2024-09-13 with reprex v2.1.1
